# More than 2TB partitions

Tags: partitioning

I have a HP Gen8 server with 3 main partition. home, home1 and home2. for home1, I have mounted two 1TB hard disks with each others (ext4) and I have done the same for home2.
as I am running some bioinformatic processes, I need that my home partition volume to be more than 4TB. 
I have tried to make a 6TB partition at the beginning but I think because of MS-DOS partition standard, I could not to do this.

Now, Is there any solution that without any break-down of my OS (Ubuntu server 14.04.1) I can merge the two other 2TB partitions to my home partition and grow its size to 6 TB? I have installed the Gnome graphic env on my server, too. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: gParted live dvd and choose "merge" partitions?

Answer (score 2):

The Master Boot Record (MBR) partitioning scheme doesn't support over-2TiB disks. You haven't said what sizes your physical disks are, but if some of them are over 2TiB in size, you're either under-utilizing them or you're using them with the newer GUID Partition Table (GPT) system, which has no problems with such disks and can handle much larger partitions, too.

I recommend you read [the Wikipedia page on GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) and at least the first two sections of my [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`) documentation.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) This will give you the background information required to revise your question. When you do, be sure to include information on the number and sizes of your existing disks as well as the current partitioning system. Try using `sudo parted /dev/sda print` on the first disk, and similar commands on the rest of them, and post the output in your edited question.